# how to change a certain value of a column in a row without updating the whole row Java Derby Data Base

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

i have a row like that :

ID===Name===Price===Quantity

04===LCDs===630===20

now i am trying to subtract 1 or more each time someone buy a LCD from the database

what i am able to do with my knowledge is to :

-get data as a String and convert to int

-then subtract

-then execute this statement "UPDATE Store_HOUSE SET ID=04,Name='LCDs',Price=630,Quantity="+ newValue ;

that works well but iam sure there is a better way ... like if i can specify the exact column that will be changed instead of having to pass the whole row (which is lot more than what's in the Example =\ )to change only one column .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you set the column type of Quanitty to INT?

then you can do it via update store_house set Quantity = Quantity - 1 where blabla...

Comment: yes Quantity is INTEGER Not Null , will try that and let you know

Comment: it worked thanks very much :D , but i wounder what will happen it subtracts from Zero ... it will return an sql exception  or so right !

Comment: If a negative quantity would be an error, you could check for that before allowing somebody to buy a LCD. Like the way amazon.com displays "Only 5 left in stock!"

Comment: looking at it know its a funny thing what i said about the sql exception for a negative value :P i was in a hurry when i wrote that :D .... thanks @BryanPendleton for Noting that, i will let it be checked in Java first ... and its great what you said about the Amazon.com idea it will add a fine touch to the GUI =) ... thank you very much